# how to set this model (yoloV4) (type:TFlite) in code. TensorFlow Lite image classification iOS example is there but they use different models

Tags: ios, swift, object-detection, tflite, yolov4

My model properties input/ output are in Flot32.

existing code available in github.
[code][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUrrM.png)(https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/image_classification/ios)

- checked the model in netron.app
- not able to set up the input and output in code.